# Need Help getting part from JSON in php

Tags: php, json

Need help in getting some part from my json. I already search for this on website and google but didn't find good example. This my json :

```
{
"_doc": "lusti",
"id": 123456,
"title": "Dokumenku dari Json",
"parsel": {
    "_doc": "parsel",
    "id": 3256,
    "doc_type": "Word",
    "title": "bendahara12.doc",
    "download_link": {
        "Word": [
            {
                "label": "doc1",
                "file": "http://example.com/file_doc1.doc"
            },
            {
                "label": "doc2",
                "file": "http://example.com/file_doc2.doc"
            },
            {
                "label": "doc3",
                "file": "http://example.com/file_doc3.doc"
            },
            {
                "label": "doc4",
                "file": "http://example.com/file_doc4.doc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and this my table :

```
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $json['???']; ?>">Doc 1</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $json['???']; ?>">Doc 2</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $json['???']; ?>">Doc 3</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="<?php echo $json['???']; ?>">Doc 4</a></td>
```

i need get link for my download button. look like :

```
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="http://example.com/file_doc1.doc">Doc 1</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="http://example.com/file_doc2.doc">Doc 2</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="http://example.com/file_doc3.doc">Doc 3</a></td>
<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="http://example.com/file_doc4.doc">Doc 4</a></td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse `JSON data` using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$array = json_decode($json_string,true);
```

Now you can get data in array format. Now you need to write `foreach loop` for retrieve download link data.Like below:

```
$download_link = $array['parsel']['download_link']['Word'];
foreach($download_link as $key=>$val){
    echo '<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="' . $val['file'] . '">'. $val['label'] .'</a></td>';
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode to use your json as an array in php :

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Then if you know your json structure will remain the same, you can directly traverse your array to loop through the download links :

```
foreach($data['parsel']['download_link']['Word'] as $k => $link) {
    echo '<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="' . $link['file'] . '">'. $link['label'] .'</a></td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use json_decode(); this would parse JSON data:

```
$array = json_decode($json_string,true);
```

Then you can write a foreach loop for the download link:

```
$download_link = $array['parsel']['download_link']['Word'];
foreach($download_link as $key=>$val){
    echo '<td class="tg-baqh"><a class="btn" href="' . $val['file'] . '">'. $val['label'] .'</a></td>';
}
```